# Is $\sum _{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{x \sin nx}{2^n}$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Is $\sum _{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{x \sin nx}{2^n}$  uniformly convergent  on $\mathbb R$?

Can anyone please give me some hint to proceed ?

Comment: It does not. Take $x=k\frac {\pi} 2$ with $k$ large.

Comment: Shouldn't $k$ need to be odd for this to work?